# Attach Function Name To JQuery Dialog Button

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on creating a dialog plugin  using JQuery Dialog . Below are the parameters which can be passed . It includes button text which user wants to add and call back function name which would be executed on click of that button .

```
    var settings = $.extend({
        message: 'Your action is successful',
        title: 'Message',
        showButton: true,
        buttonText: 'OK',
        onButtonClick: 'OnButtonClick',
        allowClose: true
    }, options);
```

I am facing issues to attach that function name to click event of the button . I am trying to do something like below but it throws error .

```
    $('#dialog-message').dialog({
        buttons: [{
            text: settings.buttonText,
            click: window[settings.onButtonClick]()

        }],
        closeOnEscape: true,
        close: function (e) {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
    });
```

Any  suggestions How can I attach that Function Name to click event as I only have the function name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callers of your plugin should provide a callback for the `onButtonClick` option rather than a string. Like so:

```
function OnButtonClick(){
   //does some cool stuff
}

var settings = $.extend({
    message: 'Your action is successful',
    title: 'Message',
    showButton: true,
    buttonText: 'OK',
    onButtonClick: OnButtonClick,
    allowClose: true
}, options);
```

And then you could bind the incoming function like this:

```
$('#dialog-message').dialog({
    buttons: [{
        text: settings.buttonText,
        click: settings.onButtonClick
    }],
    closeOnEscape: true,
    close: function (e) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
});
```

This is possible because the `onButtonClick` variable now holds a reference to the callback that the user of your plugin provided (as opposed to a string) through the `settings` they used to initialize the plugin.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @user2009755: Glad it helped. And welcome to StackOverflow! You could mark this as answer if this helped. The about page (http://stackoverflow.com/about) would help get an understanding about how this site works!